# How to use HashLocationStrategy for router in angular2-beta.20 in dart?

Tags: dart, angular2-routing, angular2-router

I tried to use the router in angular2-beta.20 in Dart with the HashLocationStrategy. 
But I couldn't find any docs, except for 
[this link to angular2-beta.15 docs](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/angular2/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2.router/HashLocationStrategy-class.html), which are incomplete. 
The example shows TypeScript imports instead of Dart ones.

So I tried to import `package:angular2/router.dart`, but the Dart Analyzer keeps complaining that it can not find `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy`

Also I don't know, how to write the import exactly, because a top-level provide function, as in the example above, seems non existent. 
`provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some research I found the following:

- `LocationStrategy` and `HashLocationStrategy` are now part of 
  `package:angular2/platform/common.dart` instead of `package:angular2/router.dart`.
- The `bootstrap()`- method is platform specific, so we need to import `package:angular2/platform/browser.dart`.
- We need to import `package:angular2/router.dart` to have `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` available in `bootstrap()` method.

Here is a working code example for the dart file initializing :

```
// needed to import "bootstrap" method
import 'package:angular2/platform/browser.dart';

// needed to import LocationStrategy and HashLocationStrategy
import 'package:angular2/platform/common.dart';

// needed for Provider class
import 'package:angular2/angular2.dart';

// needed to import ROUTER_PROVIDERS
import 'package:angular2/router.dart'; 

// import your app_component as root component for angular2
import 'app_component.dart';

void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    const Provider(LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy)
  ]);
}
```

Hope this helps somebody! :)