# How do I deploy an AngularDart web page in Git Pages?

Tags: angular, dart, github-pages, angular-dart

By default, Angular deploys `pub serve` with *root/web/* as the root folder for *index.html*. GitHub (on the gh-pages branch) assumes it is in the root project folder.

Has anyone seen this done with a GitHub page? Would I be forced to convert the code from Dart to JS and use the GitHub folder structure?

Comment: GH Pages is for serving *static* sites, you will need to compile your app to serve it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this wasn't the smoothest, but taking jonrsharpe's advice (GitHub is for static web pages), I made sure to grab a *dart2js* [transformer](https://webdev.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dart2js-transformer), throw that in my *pubspec.yaml*:

`transformers:
- $dart2js:
    minify: true`

and then ran *pub build*. That gave me the JS form of the web page in a *build* folder.

I already had `- dart_to_js_script_rewriter` in my pubspec, but I think that is used on the fly, using *pub serve*, to view in JS.

The non-smoothness comes from the fact that I moved those newly-built files into the root project folder (for GitHub) and had to append the project name to any file references in *index.html*:

- /project/style.css
- /project/main.dart.js

That produced a successful GitHub page (on *gh-pages* branch, of course).

Side note:
The Location and HashLocationStrategy are in there, but I don't believe they are doing anything, other than compiling properly.

[peanut](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/peanut) does the dart2js build and copies the files into root without having to switch the *gh-pages*. Pretty nice. It appears to remove certain files and folders (like the README file) in the process, but it's a decent little pub package.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`peanut`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/peanut).

One-time installation:

```
pub global activate peanut
```

Use:

```
cd path/to/my_angular_project
peanut
```

Upload the `gh-pages` branch to github:

```
git push origin --set-upstream gh-pages
```

Comment: matanlurey pointed that out as well, but I didn't see how that would get things working on GitHub. What am I missing there?

Comment: I tried it out. It runs the *pub build* and copies the files into root. That's cool. For some reason I still need to alter the references to include the github project folder. It appears that the gh-pages branch lags behind a bit, is slow to update, or something a little off.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure `HashLocationStrategy`

See [Location and HashLocationStrategy stopped working in beta.16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36861628/location-and-hashlocationstrategy-stopped-working-in-beta-16/36861629#36861629) to make the router work.

`root/web/` is served as the root web folder, therefore there should be no difference. If you add it to GH-Pages so that it's not on root, then you need to set `<base href="/someDir">` or provide `const Provider(APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/someDir')` needs to be provided.

Comment: That lead me to an up-to-date way to access those libraries: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39097037/how-to-use-hashlocationstrategy-for-router-in-angular2-beta-20-in-dart

I'm still figuring out how to tell GitHub to listen.

Answer (score 1):

I've filed https://github.com/dart-lang/angular2/issues/242 to see if we can get a concrete example of how to do this either on the AngularDart site or something similar.

There is a utility by one of our developers called `peanut` that can help:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/peanut